# PHP Config Variable Definition in Terms of File Upload

Tags: php, file, cakephp, configuration, upload

I am using cakephp 2.x and in order to do file uploads, I have set the following variables to custom values that I found on the internet.

```
upload_max_filesize    = 110MB
max_post_size          = 120MB
max_execution_time     = 10800 (seconds)
max_input_time         = 10800 (seconds)
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10800 (seconds)
```

What I need help with is understanding if all of these variables need to be changed in order to allow the uploading of files with sizes that range from 30 MB to 105 MB.

I understand the `upload_max_filesize`, and that `max_post_size` is the size of the posted information, including the file and any forms and other data.

What exactly do the other 3 mean?  Does the execution time include the time it takes to upload? Same question with the input time.  What exactly does the last variable (`session.gc`) do?

Be aware that I searched the internet for the changes required to allow for large file uploading, and I did the same changes that the site showed, so no comments or questions as to why I made those changes. I just followed what someone else did to upload large files.  If I can find the site I will update this question with a link to it.

PLEASE, don't just post the definition of the variables. I was able to find those online too, the only reason I posted this question is because I am having a hard time understanding how they relate to file uploading.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this parameters are related to the php function [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set).

A list of all configuration options can be found in the [PHP documentation Appendix / List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

**[max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)** *integer*: This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.
The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details.
You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.
Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

**[max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)** *integer*: This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. It is measured from the moment of receiving all data on the server to the start of script execution.

**[session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)** *integer*: session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. So, I am assuming file uploads are not affected by either then.  Input time is after the file has been fully uploaded. But execution time is still confusing. And session seems unrelated to file uploads, so I will change that back to default. Can you please confirm. Thanks

Comment: @RXC: file uploads (not speaking of threatments after upload) are not affected by the 3 options I explained. max_execution_time is the time PHP spends running **on its own** (e.g. time spent within file_get_contents() or exec() is not taking in count).

Comment: Awesome, Thank you, its good to know what those variables actually do.